# Plot a variable number of vectors at once?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, struct, plot

I was wondering:

Assume I have a structure:

```
s(1).Xval=[1 2 3];
s(2).Xval=[1 2 3 4];
s(3).Xval=[1 2 3];

s(1).Yval=[1 2 3];
s(2).Yval=[4 3 2 1];
s(3).Yval=[3 2 1];
```

Now I want to plot these three lines in one plot. I can do this by:

```
plot(s(1).Xval,s(1).Yval,s(2).Xval,s(2).Yval,s(3).Xval,s(3).Yval);
```

This is possible because MATLAB offers the opportunity for a variable number of input arguments of the plot function, by means of the syntax:

```
plot(X1,Y1,...,Xn,Yn)
```

My question is: is there a way to call this function without a predefined number of plots? So in this case, I plotted three lines, but in case i do not know upfront how many lines I want to plot, is this syntax still possible?

I am of course aware that I could do this by using `Hold All` and a `For` loop. However, I ask this because I would like to avoid a loop if neccesary. Is there an elegant solution for this? Or should I just resort to using a loop?

Edit: There was indeed a typo with the indexes. s.Xval(1) instead of s(1).Xval

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/techdoc/ref/varargin.html). Hope useful

Comment: Please note that your example is wrong, because `s.Xval` must have the same amounts of elements in each row. The same goes for `s.Yval`.

Comment: @EitanT: I suspect it's supposed to be `s(1).Xval; s(2).Xval`, etc.

Comment: @Jonas I believe that in that case the proposed answer should be slightly different.

Comment: @EitanT I couldn't see why it should be different. Could you expand on that? I had assumed Johann3s wanted plot(s(1).xVal, s(1).yVal, s(2).xVal, s(2).yVal, ...). Does my answer not give the same result?

Comment: Thanks, there was indeed a typo, I changed it. And I think the answer should indeed not be different. However the current answers lead me to think that just plotting in a for loop is the most appropriate solution?

Comment: @Johann3s: yes, I'd agree that a loop is the most convenient solution.

Comment: I added another answer for a solution without a loop, which I think is an elegant solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found another method which is to my mind fairly nice.

```
plotdata = cell(length(s)*2,1);
plotdata(1:2:end) = {s.Xval};
plotdata(2:2:end) = {s.Yval};
plot(axes,plotdata{:});
```

This code is straightforward and easy to read, and discards the need of a loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with [plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) function. Documentation mentions that:

> If Xn or Yn are matrices, they must be 2-D and the same size, and the columns of Yn are plotted against the columns of Xn. plot automatically chooses colors and line styles in the order specified by ColorOrder and LineStyleOrder properties of current axes.

To make X and Y matrices, you will need to pad them with NaNs. Like this:

```
X = [1 2 3 NaN
     1 2 3 4
     1 2 3 NaN]
Y = [1 2 3 NaN
     4 3 2 1
     3 2 1 NaN]
```

Since plot function plots column against column, and you want row againts row, you will need to transpose them.

```
plot(X',Y','Marker','x')
```

will give you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a typo, so the correct struct is this:

```
s(1).Xval=[1 2 3];
s(2).Xval=[1 2 3 4];
s(3).Xval=[1 2 3];

s(1).Yval=[1 2 3];
s(2).Yval=[4 3 2 1];
s(3).Yval=[3 2 1];
```

% collect all data into one cell

```
c = {};
for k = 1 : length(s)
    c = cat(2, c, {s(k).Xval}, {s(k).Yval});
end
```

% and plot:

```
plot(c{:});
```

Note, that `c{:}` is not a single variable, but as number of elements of `c`

**Update:** without the loop, but ugly

```
c = reshape(reshape({s.Xval, s.Yval}, length(s), [])', [], 1);
plot(c{:});
```

Comment: There was indeed a typo. Thanks for your answer. The only thing is that I wanted to avoid a loop, and now you created a new one. It seems to me that it is then more appropriate to just plot in the loop?

Comment: @Johann3s, see an update without a loop. If you need this frequently, I suggest to put this into a function, so you can call: `plot_struct(s);`

Comment: Both answers are fine, but I accept yours because of the extra effort of your edit!

Comment: But also because the cell structure was actually exactly what I was looking for: Because with one command: `c{:}` it expands to multiple function input arguments.

Comment: I added another answer for a solution without a loop, which I think is an elegant solution as well.